# Binary sequences with runs of $0$s and $1$s

Tags: combinatorics

How many binary sequences of length 20 are there that
(a) Start with a run of $0$s—that is, a consecutive sequence of (at least) one $0$—
then a run of $1$s, then a run of $0$s, then a run of $1$s, and finally finish with a
run of $0$s?
(b) Repeat part (a) with the constraint that each run is of length at least 2.

My approach:
The runs should be of the following type
$$
0's,1's,0's,1's,0's
$$
If $x_{i}$ represents the number of $0$'s or $1$'s
$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=20
$$
For $(a)$:
$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=15
$$
Since $x_{i}>0$,
The answer would be:
$$
\binom{19}{4}
$$
Similarly for $(b)$:
$$
\binom{14}{4}
$$
Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is correct, one way you can make sure of it is the following, the formulae you used for the number of solutions of:

$$ x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3} + \cdots + x_{k} = n $$

Is correct based on your notes. The other thing you need to make sure is that this actually counts the sequences you want, a way to do that is to convice yourself that a sequence of 0's and 1's as above can give you a solution to

$$ x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5} = 20 $$

where $x_{i} > 0 $ (for a) and vice versa. But that is pretty clear from your point that $x_{i}$ represents the number of 0's or 1's that they count the same thing, so your point holds fully.

So all in all, there is no point in which your approach has ambiguity.